# Selecting text problem

Tags: gnome, display, text, 13.10

Hello I'm new with Ubuntu but I have this problem that drives my nuts
If I select some text (doesn't matter in what program ) the highlight just keep jumping at the end or on some random word in the line

Comment: Your description is very unclear - can you provide a screenshot? Edit your question to show us the link and someone will incorporate it into your question.

Comment: open **system setting** > **Mouse and Touchpad** > **Test Your Setting** .Probably more on hardware. Try another mouse if not working.